# File name issue in AWS lambda s3 file unzip python

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have lambda function as below

```
from __future__ import print_function

import urllib
import zipfile
import boto3
import io
import mimetypes

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = 'staging-bucket'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'].encode('utf8'))
        obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        with io.BytesIO(obj["Body"].read()) as tf:
            # rewind the file
            tf.seek(0)
            # Read the file as a zipfile and process the members
            with zipfile.ZipFile(tf, mode = 'r') as zipf:
                for file in zipf.infolist():
                    fileName = file.filename
                    contentType, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(fileName)
                    contentType = contentType or 'application/octet-stream'
                    filePath = "playable/staging/" + key.replace("package.zip", "") + fileName
                    putFile = s3.put_object(ACL = 'public-read', Bucket = "unzipped-bucket", Key = filePath, Body = zipf.read(file), ContentType = contentType)


    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e

    return
```

It takes **zip** file from s3 bucket and extracts it to another s3 bucket

the function runs successfully, but the extracted filename has the zip file name as prefix, see below pictures for reference

***Source zip file :* package-1542108930.zip**

***Source zip contents:***
 [source zip files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG4vn.png)

***Extracted folder contents:***
[extracted files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agiHi.png)

I'm unable to find the bug in python script, 
any help will appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is this line:

```
filePath = "playable/staging/" + key.replace("package.zip", "") + fileName
```

Note that you're removing the string `package.zip` but (as you can see from the "prefixes"), the string is actually `package-1542108930.zip`.

Try:

```
filePath = "playable/staging/" + fileName
```

If you simply do not want any name.

If you want to maintain the timestamp, then:

```
filePath = "playable/staging/" + key.replace("package-", "").replace(".zip", "") + fileName
```

Comment: your code will work for only one zip file, the problem is every zip has different names (timestamps)

Comment: Yes- you must programmatically create that replacement string with the right one; but the reason you have this problem is because your current "package.zip" string does not match what you need to replace. There's not enough context in your question for me to know how you could do this, but I'll take a guess from the S3 event.

Comment: If this _still_ isn't what you want, then can you please provide an example of what the right path would be.

Comment: with your code `filePath = "playable/staging/" + fileName`  the zip is not getting extracted

Comment: i have many package-{timestamp}.zip files with diffrent timestamp, i would like to extract their contents in different bucket.